# Installing ubuntu with yaboot

Tags: boot, mac-mini, yaboot

I've just got a old used macbook g4 that as only debian installed in it and I wanted to install ubuntu,but I've no idea of how to use yaboot to install ubuntu,can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dual boot both distros?

Having tinkered with both Debian (Wheezy - 6) and Ubuntu on an old Mac Powerbook G4, I actually would suggest sticking with Debian. If you do wish to try to install Ubuntu, you will need to download the 32 bit ppc disc. Yaboot is used as the bootloader on older ("new world") Macs. It will be installed automatically installed if you try to install the Ubuntu distro.